# Redux toolkit data is not fetching

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

The problem I'm facing my accidents array is empty for some reason, and receiving `<h3>You have no accidents </h3>`. `console.log(accidents._id);` this log returns `undefined`. Thank you in advance for the help and taking a look into this.

Slice:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import accidentService from "./accidentService";

const initialState = {
  accidents: [],
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: "",
};

// Create new accident report
export const createAccident = createAsyncThunk(
  "home/create",
  async (accidentData, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await accidentService.createAccidentReport(accidentData, token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

// Get accident reports
export const getAccidents = createAsyncThunk(
  "accidents/getAll",
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await accidentService.getAccidents(token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

export const accidentSlice = createSlice({
  name: "accident",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => initialState,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(createAccident.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(createAccident.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.accidents.push(action.payload);
      })
      .addCase(createAccident.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getAccidents.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getAccidents.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.goals = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getAccidents.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export const { reset } = accidentSlice.actions;
export default accidentSlice.reducer;
```

Service:

```
   import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = "/api/home/accidentReport";

// Create new accident report
const createAccidentReport = async (accidentData, token) => {
  //Get token
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  const response = await axios.post(API_URL, accidentData, config);

  return response.data;
};

//Get accident reports
const getAccidents = async (token) => {
  //Get token
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };
  const response = await axios.get("/api/home/allAccidents", config);

  return response.data;
};

const accidentService = {
  createAccidentReport,
  getAccidents,
};

export default accidentService;
```

View:

```
import "./ReportTable.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getAccidents } from "../../Features/accidentReport/accidentSlice";

const ReportTable = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { accidents, isLoading, isError, message } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.accident
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAccidents());
  }, [dispatch, getAccidents]);

  console.log(accidents._id);
  return (
    <>
      <section>
        {accidents.length > 0 ? (
          <div>
            {accidents.map((accident) => (
              <p key={accident._id}>{accident._id}</p>
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <h3>You have no accidents </h3>
        )}
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default ReportTable;
```

Comment: console what backend `response.data` is.

Comment: Already found solution, it was a typo in my slice ` state.goals = action.payload; ` should have been ` state.accidents = action.payload; `. Even though I was scanning slice line by line.